# No result-message from JsonResult method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, knockout.js

I went through the suggested related topics before asking this question but none of them could solve my problem. So in advance, sorry for a possible dubplicate..

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application I have following function that is attached to a button:

```
save: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Save")",
        type: "post",
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: "application/json",
        succes: function (result) { alert(result.message) },
    });
}
```

In my Controller I have a JsonResult-method like this:

```
public JsonResult Save(Person person)
{
    //process person-parameter and send message back
    var message = "Dummy result-message";
    return Json(new { message });
}
```

And these are the JavaScript - files I have referenced:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-1.2.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I debugged the application using breakpoints and the button - event is fired like it should and the method in the Controller is called. The processing of the Person-parameter is done and I call the return - statment. But the problem is: I don't get an alert...

For a couple of hours now I've been looking on the internet on how to solve this but I can't seem to find the solution. I hope any of you guys can get me back on the right track. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your success function is named incorrectly in the code above. You have it spelled 'succes'. It should be 'success'.

Comment: Jesus, stupid me.. Thanks a lot, it works! :D Definitly should have seen that one..

Comment: Been there, done that :)

Comment: How can I mark this question as solved now as there's no 'real answer' been given..?

Comment: Maybe @Malevolence want to answer it. If not answer it yourself and mark it as *Answered*.

Comment: That is kind of lame, asking a question and marking someone else's alswer as my own.. Just answer it and I'll mark it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*success* setting is misspelled :)